# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(): Change the 30-minute timeout

Tags: .net, system.diagnostics

I am working on an application that uses Process.Start() to launch applications. We have discovered that on some occasions, the process never starts. That's tolerable. What isn't tolerable is the 30-minute period that it takes for Windows to throw an unhelpful "The operation was canceled by the user" exception when the process fails to start. We need to get this timeout down to something more reasonable.

Thusfar I have failed to find information explaining this timeout or how I can configure it. I'm open to solutions that launches a timer and kills the process if the timer expires.

Comment: can't you check in the code to see if it failed to start, and if so, try again?

Comment: You mean in the applications that this program is starting? I have no control over those.

Comment: you can create the process like this: `var proc = new Process(); ... proc.Start();`. Then you can should be able to interact with the `proc` and see if it's running.

Comment: If you said it was a 2 Minute timeout instead of a 30 minute timeout I would have suspected a UAC dialog was being presented, but what the heck are you doing on your server that the OS can not get around to starting a process up for 30 minutes?